# how to split object array value of month/year into 2 values like month and year?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am taking the input of card expiry month and year in one field. 
Now i want to split it into month and year, So that i can pass data in my POST call as seperate.
Current object looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHvqx.png)

I followed this article 
[jQuery how to split today's date from input into month, day, year when datepicker NOT used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223207/jquery-how-to-split-todays-date-from-input-into-month-day-year-when-datepicke)

but it contains different input-fields.

JavaScript:

```
 var data = $("#form-ct").serializeArray();
                    orderJson= {
                        "BillTo.Address.City" : userData.data[0].Addresses.CurrentAddress.City,
                        "BillTo.Address.State": userData.data[0].Addresses.CurrentAddress.State,
                        "BillTo.Address.Street": userData.data[0].Addresses.CurrentAddress.Street,
                        "BillTo.Address.Zip": userData.data[0].Addresses.CurrentAddress.Zip,
                        "BillTo.Name.First": userData.data[0].Identity.Name.First,
                        "BillTo.Name.Surname": userData.data[0].Identity.Name.Surname,
                        "stoken": stoken,
                        "CreditCard.Expires.Month" : data[3].value,
                        "CreditCard.Expires.Year" : data[3].value,
                        "CreditCard.Number": data[2].value,
                        "CreditCard.SecurityCode": data[1].value,
```

Any Idea how can i split ? 
Do i have to use split function ?

```
var arr_dateText = dateText.split("/");
startmonth = arr_dateText[0];
startyear = arr_dateText[2];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using following code:

```
var date = $("#datetime").val().split('/');
var SplitDate = {
                 month: parseInt(date[0], 10),
                 year: parseInt(date[1], 10)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have it.

```
var date = '10/2017';
var parts = date.split('/');
var month = parts[0];
var year = parts[1];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp). Example code for your use case:

```js
var obj = {
'CreditCardExpiresMonth' : '12/1988',
'CreditCardExpiresYear' : '12/1988'
}
var dateValue = obj.CreditCardExpiresMonth;
obj.CreditCardExpiresMonth = dateValue.substr( 0, dateValue.indexOf( '/' ) );
obj.CreditCardExpiresYear = dateValue.substr( dateValue.indexOf( '/' ) + 1 );

alert( obj.CreditCardExpiresMonth );
alert( obj.CreditCardExpiresYear );
```